# PyCharm - Django shell/shell_plus in Debug mode - autocomplete

Tags: python, django, intellij-idea, pycharm, ipython

I've created a configuration in `PyCharm` that allows me to debug Django shell/shell_plus. It works correctly but I would like it also to autocomplete methods and attributes like it does when executed this way:

```
python manage.py shell_plus
```

It probably needs to use `iPython` which I installed but I don't know where to set this up.

[image]

Do you know what to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [docs](https://django-extensions.readthedocs.io/en/latest/shell_plus.html#interactive-python-shells):

```
python manage.py shell_plus --ipython
```